# How to set AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY when using 'AS SELECT'

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a temporary table and right now I am doing something like this:

`CREATE IF NOT EXISTS TABLE tempdb.student AS (SELECT * FROM student LIMIT 0)`

then

`ALTER TABLE tempdb.student MODIFY id INT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY`

However, I need to find a way to do this without the `ALTER` statement because both statements are getting ran together and if the table has already been created, I am getting an error because of the multiple primary keys. Any advice? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can define columns, indexes, table options, and partitioning before the `AS` keyword.

```
CREATE IF NOT EXISTS TABLE tempdb.student (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(10),
  enroll_date DATE,
  ...etc...
)
AS SELECT * FROM student LIMIT 0
```

This is the *only* way you can set some column or table options, such as auto-increment.

But it means you have to define *all* the columns, not just `id`.

Since you are using `LIMIT 0` it means you don't actually want any rows from the source table. I guess you are just trying to duplicate the table structure, but none of the data.

In that case, you might like to use the following instead:

```
CREATE IF NOT EXISTS TABLE tempdb.student LIKE student;
```

This duplicates other column and table options, and indexes, and partitions. The new table will have the AUTO_INCREMENT option for its primary key.

Comment: It looks like it might be best to use `LIKE` then; is it possible to add additional columns as well similar to how we can using the first method? Thanks for the help!

Comment: No, it just creates a table exactly like the original table. To customize the columns, you can either use the first method I showed above, or else use `CREATE TABLE ... LIKE ...` and then subsequently use `ALTER TABLE` to add extra columns.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can explicitly check if the table exists (you need to be careful if the code can be executed in parallel):

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) INTO @exists
FROM
    information_schema.tables
WHERE
        table_schema = 'tempdb'
    AND table_name = 'student'
;

IF @exists = 0 THEN
    CREATE TABLE tempdb.student AS (SELECT * FROM student LIMIT 0); -- or use LIKE syntax 
    ALTER TABLE tempdb.student MODIFY id INT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
END IF;
```

2. If your temporary table needed for the session only, I'd use `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ... LIKE ...` and alter as required.